# Custom Google Sign In Button does not appear in Svelte

Tags: svelte, google-signin

I'm trying to implement the Custom Google Sign In Button example on Google's guide but it doesn't even call the callback. If I use plain HTML and Javascript, it works but not in Svelte:

CustomGoogleSignInButton.svelte

```
<script>
  function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    console.log("Logged in as: " + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
  }
  function onFailure(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render("my-signin2", {
      scope: "profile email",
      width: 240,
      height: 50,
      longtitle: true,
      theme: "dark",
      onsuccess: onSuccess,
      onfailure: onFailure
    });
  }
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script
    src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton"
    async
    defer>

  </script>
</svelte:head>

<div id="my-signin2" />
```

I also do have the meta in the head tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onload=renderButton` means 'when this script loads, call the *global* function named `renderButton`. Functions declared in your `<script>` block are **local** to the component, so there is no global `renderButton`.

You could solve it by adding the function to the window object...

```js
window.renderButton = function() {
  gapi.signin2.render("my-signin2", {
    scope: "profile email",
    width: 240,
    height: 50,
    longtitle: true,
    theme: "dark",
    onsuccess: onSuccess,
    onfailure: onFailure
  });
}
```

...but you might also be able to use the local function instead like so:

```html
<svelte:head>
  <script
    src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"
    on:load={renderButton}
    async
    defer>

  </script>
</svelte:head>
```

If that works, it's preferable to polluting the `window` object.

Comment: That way is alot better! Thanks!